# stuck with the logic in looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I was stuck in the middle
SO i placed the sample data which will represent my data set up
MAP and NET_P WERE SAME

```
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_O
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_O
        ([A] INT, [B] INT, [RESET] INT, [P] NUMERIC(22,6), [MAP] NUMERIC(22,6), [NET_P] NUMERIC(22,6), [MAP_PER] INT, [PRICE_RESET] INT, [RESET_P_VALUE] INT, [PRICE] NUMERIC(22,6), [PT] INT)
    ;

    INSERT INTO #TEMP_O
        ([A], [B], [RESET], [P], [MAP], [NET_P], [MAP_PER], [PRICE_RESET], [RESET_P_VALUE], [PRICE], [PT])
    VALUES
        (1404592, 1, NULL, '39', '165.18', '165.18', 1, 1, 50, 39, 10),
        (1404592, 2, NULL, '39', '165.18', '165.18', 1, 1, 50, 39, 10),
        (1404592, 3, NULL, '39', '165.18', '165.18', 1, 1, 50, 39, 10),
        (1404592, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 2, 60, 42, 10),
        (1404592, 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 2, 60, 48, 10),
        (1404592, 6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 3, 60, 49, 10),
        (1404592, 7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 3, 70, 56, 10),
        (1404592, 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 3, 70, 65, 10),
        (1404592, 9, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 4, 70, 69, 10),
        (1404676, 1, NULL, '70', '165.18', '165.18', 1, 1, 52, 70, 10),
        (1404676, 2, NULL, '70', '165.18', '165.18', 1, 1, 52, 79, 10),
        (1404676, 3, NULL, '70', '165.18', '165.18', 1, 1, 52, 89, 10),
        (1404676, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 2, 56, 90, 10),
        (1404676, 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 2, 56, 97, 10),
        (1404676, 6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 2, 56, 97, 10),
        (1404676, 7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 3, 63, 98, 10),
        (1404676, 8, '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, 4, 4, 63, 98, 10),
        (1404676, 9, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 4, 4, 63, 99, 10)
    ;
```

I got the result but it was taking time i used loops.
need a result like following

the required output will be as follows.

[image]

Comment: I`m not sure who gave this 2 upvotes but there is no clear question here - merely a statement of requirements - and there does not appear to be any research effort as no simplified code example displaying the problem appears. Please edit this for clarity as to what your question is and include a simplified piece of code displaying the problem.

Comment: @SMM thanks for bringing notice. those were the conditions. since it was taking long to read so i removed the statements. Now i put the result and input.Not i got the result by using loops

Comment: Are you trying to write an update statement that will replace NULL with numbers?